# Handle the specific error that express sends in React

Tags: reactjs, express, handle

My client sends a user register request to my express server.
If it is successfull express sends the client to /success
If it faces an issue it sends the client to /Error

Right now I'm trying to send the client to a specific page which explains about the error. For example, if the username is already in the database, I would like to send the user to /Exists

What would be the best way to do so? as for now what I do is this:

The express server sends 500 on connection error, 200 on success. The client waits for res, if it is successfull it sends to /success and if not it sends to /error. The problem is that it is not really scaleable, as when I send 302 when the user is already in database I can't seem to understand how to make a statement that checks which status code it exactly is. res.status does show the error code but it values "null" if I try to use it in "if" statement

Comment: Is this in the context of server-side rendered react?

Comment: "The express server sends 500 on connection error"

Can you wrap the database error in a try catch? When it throws with the particular error caused by the user already existing, then you can redirect with a 302